# How to set default landing page in react router v5 based on roles

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have my router setup like below :

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, isAllowed, ...rest }) {
   
   return (
     <Route
       {...rest}
       render={({ location }) =>
         isAllowed ? <Component {...props} /> : (
           <Redirect to={{
             pathname: '/Unauthorized',
             state: { from: location }
           }} />
         )
       }
     />
   );
 }

return (

<Router history={history}>
<Switch>

    <PrivateRoute component={SearchPage} exact path={["/", "/search"]} 
     isAllowed={hasSearchAccess} />

     <PrivateRoute component={SearchResultsPage} exact path="/searchResults" 
     isAllowed={hasSearchAccess} />

      <PrivateRoute component={ApproverPage} exact path="/approve" isAllowed= 
      {hasApproverAccess} />
       </Route>

     </Switch>
   </Router>
 );
```

Now based on UserRole(an different boolean variable) need to show the Default landing page. And that route should run only once the user has logged in. And on refresh the page should not redirect to default landing page. How can this be achieved?

Comment: React Router has example dealing with this: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow. You could also use conditional rendering in the `Route` render function (https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func)

Comment: the problem is i need to allow routes based on "user permission" and show default landing page by using "user roles" .. i am able to restrict users based on "user permission".. how can i tell react router to run only once , a particular route , once the user has logged   based on a diffrent parameter?

Comment: Thank you @Ayushya , was able to achieve the functionality using conditional rendering.